# Installing Kubernetes on Ubuntu gives "The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?"

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes

I am installing Kubernetes on my Ubuntu 20.4 machine.

This is the steps I have done:

1. Install Docker from https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/
2. Install Docker Compose with `sudo apt install docker-compose`

Now I am installing Kubernetes:

Dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl
```

Google key

```
sudo curl -fsSLo /usr/share/keyrings/kubernetes-archive-keyring.gpg https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg
```

Repository

```
echo"deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/kubernetes-archive-keyring.gpg] https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main"| sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
```

Install kubernetes

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y kubelet kubeadm kubectl
```

Test:

```
kubectl version
```

And this gives me error:

```
WARNING: This version information is deprecated and will be replaced with the output from kubectl version --short.  Use --output=yaml|json to get the full version.
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"24", GitVersion:"v1.24.4", GitCommit:"95ee5ab382d64cfe6c28967f36b53970b8374491", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2022-08-17T18:54:23Z", GoVersion:"go1.18.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Kustomize Version: v4.5.4
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

I have Googled the error and found out that I need a Kubernetes config file in my home directory. This is the solution that I have seen the most:

```
 mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
 sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
 sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
```

My problem is that I do not have any files in /etc/kubernetes:

```
me@oter:/etc/kubernetes$ ll
total 20
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 aug.  22 12:14 ./
drwxr-xr-x 133 root root 12288 aug.  22 12:14 ../
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 aug.  22 12:14 manifests/
```

Comment: seems like you missed to create the cluster creation step https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/

Comment: @Adiii thank you, setting up cluster helped me out.

Comment: great to know, posting as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment, you need to create a cluster before performing any operation.

- Initializing your master

```
kubeadm init
```

- Installing a pod network

```
kubectl apply -f http://docs.projectcalico.org/v2.3/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/kubeadm/1.6/calico.yaml
```

- Joining your nodes

```
kubeadm join --token <token> <master-ip>:<master-port>
```

[create-cluster-kubeadm](http://pwittrock.github.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/)

[create-cluster-kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/)